# Problems aligning text field input using GridLayout

Tags: java, button, jtextfield, grid-layout

I want to make a form using java frame. I have two fields `Name` and `Age`. After entering the details, when the button is clicked, the entered data must be displayed as shown below, but I am not sure how to align it.

```
The entered data are:
     FirstName: abcd
     LastName: efg
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class DataEntry {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
         Frame frm=new Frame("DataEntry frame");
         Label lbl = new Label("Please fill this blank:");
         frm.add(lbl);
         frm.setSize(350,200);
         frm.setVisible(true);
         frm.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
             public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                     System.exit(0);
         }
        });

       Panel p = new Panel();
       Panel p1 = new Panel();
       Label jFirstName = new Label("First Name");
       TextField lFirstName = new TextField(20);
       Label jLastName =new Label("Last Name");
       TextField lLastName=new TextField(20);
       p.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
       p.add(jFirstName);
       p.add(lFirstName);
       p.add(jLastName);
       p.add(lLastName);
       Button Submit=new Button("Submit");
       p.add(Submit);
       p1.add(p);
       frm.add(p1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to use event handling part read here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html

Comment: Why are you not using Swing instead of AWT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you need to add an event to the button, when it is clicked.

```
submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
         {
             // Add the code to output the relevant details. 
         }
    }
```

Then it's up to you to add the relevant code to the method body.
You should read the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html)

Comment: Please tell me where to put these codes and what code to add inside the { }, to get the desired output

Comment: The addition of the actionlistener should be added near to the button's instantiation. (`Button Submit=new Button("Submit");`). The code in the method body should be to put the value in "Name" and the "age" value in their respective labels. `jFirstName.setText(name);`

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener to your "Submit" button:

```
Submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        myLabelForShowingTheOutput.setText("<html><body>Name: " + lFirstName + "<br>Last name: " + lLastName + "</body></html>");
    }
});
```

Note that "myLabelForShowingTheOutput" is the JLabel you want to print. The text to print is basic HTML, so the label can show multiple lines. Other way to do it without HTML would be create a JLabel for the name and another for the age. Note as well that I did put the last name in the output, because there isn't an obvious JTextField for the age.

Remember, as well, that variables should start their name in lower case, so Submit would be "submit".

Comment: I can't understand it. Could you please tell me how to code it to get the desired output?

Comment: The code is exactly the one writen in the comment. You only need too create a new JLabel called "myLabelForShowingTheOutput" and add it to the panel, as you did before with jFirstName and jLastName.